# Conditionally copy values from dataframe column to another dataframe with different length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to copy a values from a dataframe column to another dataframe if the values in two other columns are the same.

example df1:

```
identifier price
    1       nan
    1       nan 
    3       nan
    3       nan
```

and so on. There are several rows for every identifier.

In my df2, there is only one value for each identifier in "price"

example df2:

```
Identifier price
    1        3
    3        5
```

I just would like to copy the "price" values in df2 to "price" in df1. It does not matter to me if the values are copied to each column where the identifiers match or just to the first, since I will alter all but the first entry for each identifier in df1["price"] anyways.

Expected output would be still df1 because there are other columns I still need:

```
identifier price
    1        3
    1       nan 
    3        5
    3       nan
```

OR:

```
identifier price
    1        3
    1        3 
    3        5
    3        5
```

I could work with both.

I tried np.where but the different length of the dataframes causes problems. I also tried using loc, but I got stuck when defining the value that should be inserted in the cell if the condition holds.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, on='identifier', how='left')`

Comment: Or `df["identifier"].map(df2.set_index("identifier")["price"])`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped!